# SwapRateHelper fails for swap with 4W frequency: "undecidable comparison between 4W and 1M"

Tags: python, quantlib

I am using QuantLib 1.7 in Python.

I am trying to build the swap curve for MXN TIIE Swaps, which is a vanilla fixed-float with frequency of 4 weeks on both legs.

When I call SwapRateHelper I get the error message "undecidable comparison between 4W and 1M". However there is no reference to a 1M tenor anywhere on my code... I don't understand what is the problem.

```
import QuantLib as ql

tiie_index =  ql.IborIndex('TIIE', ql.Period('4W') , 1, ql.MXNCurrency(), ql.NullCalendar(), ql.Following, False, ql.Actual360())

rate = 0.02
tenor = ql.Period('12W') 
frequency = ql.EveryFourthWeek
bdays_adj = ql.Following
day_count = ql.Actual360()

h = ql.SwapRateHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate)), tenor, ql.Mexico(), frequency, bdays_adj, day_count, tiie_index)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug that was fixed in version 1.7.1; see https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/issues/28.

Comment: Thank you. Using schedule.cpp from commit 1.7.1 solves my issue.